# Work required to bring particle towards grounded plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, conductors

I have a quick question:

If you suspend a charge $q$ above a grounded conducting plane a distance $z$ above the plane, you get that the charge induces a negative surface charge on the conductor. The force of attraction on the particle is hence $$\vec{F} = - \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q^2}{(2d)^2}\hat{z}.$$ Hence to find the energy of this system when the particle is a distance $d$ above the plane, we can consider the work required to bring the charge in from infinity. The force required to oppose the electrical force above is $$\vec{F} = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q^2}{(2d)^2}\hat{z}$$ so $$W = \int^{d}_{\infty}F \cdot dI = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\int^{d}_{\infty}\frac{q^2}{4z^2}dz = -\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}\frac{q^2}{4d}.$$
Am I correct in interpreting the fact that the work is negative as a result that the particle is attracted to the plane as we bring it in and it induces surface charge on the surface of the conductor, hence the particle is naturally pulled towards the plane requiring in a sense, no external work but rather aided by the attraction force?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, -ve work is done *on the particle* if it is attracted to the plane.

This is the same as saying that useful work can be extracted by allowing the particle to approach the plane. An external force has to be applied, pointing away from the plane, to prevent the particle from accelerating. The particle moves against this force, towards the plane, so the work done *on the particle* is -ve; the work done *by the particle* is +ve.

If we move the particle away from the plane the motion is now in the same direction as the applied force, so the work done *on the particle* is +ve.

Comment: And now I click "Skip"...

Comment: @peterh me too, but I do think this answer is lazy, to say the least. Giving such answers to lazy questions does not seem to have the goal to actually help the understanding of the asker and answer the question, but rather make some sort of point about what this site is. The latter is a fair thing to do, but I think the comment section the right place to do so, not the answer section.